# Yarn throws Error: Cannot find module 'decamelize'

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, yarnpkg

I am trying to run `yarn install` in the root directory of my project. Everything worked fine until I got an error in the browser console that one of the modules cannot be found. I was building the project with no errors with `yarn install` but in the browser, I kept getting the error that one of the modules cannot be found.

I have tried to `synchronize` files in the IntelliJ editor, also `Invalidate caches and restart` in the editor, but nothing worked, I kept building the project with `yarn install` with no errors but kept getting the error in the console. After that, I ran `npm install`, and ever since that I cannot run `yarn install` anymore. I have tried to reinstall `node` to the version `10.15.3`. Ran commands `npm rebuild` and `npm install` again. For `npm install` I get the error:

```sh
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on
reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated samsam@1.3.0: This package has been deprecated in favour of
@sinonjs/samsam
npm WARN deprecated hoek@5.0.4: This version is no
longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!    
C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-19T14_25_52_551Z-debug.log
```

And if I run `yarn install` I keep getting the error:

```sh
    $ cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --no-progress --colors
  --config webpack/webpack.prod.js
      internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
          throw err;

         ^

     Error: Cannot find module 'decamelize'
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do not use two dependency management tools in the same project. You are bound to get errors. Stick to one of them. I would suggest to use yarn

1. Delete your existing node modules folder.
2. Delete all the lock files present eg. package-lock.json and yarn.lock file.
3. Run fresh yarn install command. (Be sure to update yarn to the latest version to save yourself from any unknown errors).
4. Build and test the project.